# Remove this use of constructor "Scanner(file)"

Tags: java, sonarqube, java.util.scanner, sonarqube-scan

How to fixed this sonar issue ?

```
File file = new File("/some directory");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Remove this use of constructor "Scanner(file)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1943) says:

> **Classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding should not be used**
>
> Using classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding can result in code that works fine in its "home" environment. But that code may break for customers who use different encodings in ways that are extremely difficult to diagnose and nearly, if not completely, impossible to reproduce when it's time to fix them.

To fix this issue, you should use a constructor that includes a `Charset`. For example, the `Scanner(File, Charset)` constructor. You should specify the charset you want.

```
File file = new File("/some directory");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // as an example
```